# Give myself admin priviledges in phpBB 3

Tags: phpbb

I have inherited a broken phpBB installation. It has posts and forums, but the user table is a mess.

I need to know what columns I can change in which tables to give myself full administrator privileges so that I can start using the web interface to make appropriate changes to the user table.

So far I have tried

```
update
  phpbb_users
set
  user_permissions = 'a_'
where
  username LIKE 'administrator@mysite.com'
```

But when I log in I still cannot see any of the forums and there's no options on the phpBB web page to make changes.

How do I give myself full administrator privileges?phpBB

Comment: I respect the moderator's decision to close the question, however I would argue that this is software related. It is not programming related and therefore does not belong on stackoverflow.com. It is almost operations relation and could belong on serverfaultcom but I decided this was more of a super problem. Anyway. I found the answer I needed and it is now searchable should any one else have the same problem in the future and need to know the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I had to do the following:

```
update
  phpbb_users
set
  user_permissions = ''
  ,user_type = '3'
  ,group_id = '5'
where
  username LIKE 'administrator@mysite.com'
```

Now I have access to the administrator control panel.